# Show Dialog with jQuery Mobile and ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor, dialog

I have a searchform in my ASP.NET MVC4 project.
When someone hasn't fill in one textbox, there is a message shown on the top of the page.

What I want is a dialog that appears on that moment instead of the text on the top of the page.

I tried everything, but all i get is a black square on the top of the page.

Can anyone help me with the jQuery Mobile Dialog?
Just the simpliest design is ok!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is useful for http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/